# Расположить иконки под блок

Tags: html, css

Очень долго пытаюсь решить проблему, необходимо иконки представленные на скриншоте, расположить под саму карточку товара. Пробовал z-index'ы. Ни в коем случае не думайте, что хочу чтобы сделали за меня. Хотя бы подскажите направление дальнейших действий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ссылка на сайт

https://ivanovst.ru/projects/megamarket/card.html

Comment: bitrix .... шаблон самостоятельно делаете ?

Comment: Местами блоки задать и прописать z-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант сделать перенос некоторых блоков:

1. Обернуть блок `card` в блок с атрибутом `position:relative`
2. Блок `card__stickers` вынести из блока `card` и поставить его перед блоком `card`
3. Для блока `card` добавить атрибут `position:relative`

Упрощенный код:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div class="card__stickers">
       ...
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: всё равно не выходит. сделал по вашей рекомендации и другому комменту, задав у блока цвет. нужно чтобы тень падала на кнопки

Comment: тогда только у card__content-right задать тень

Comment: Вы **не вынесли** блок с классом `card__stickers` за пределы блока с классом `card`, только что посмотрел у вас на сайте, поэтому тень не отбрасывается, проверьте еще раз.

Comment: У себя локально пробовал, сейчас загрузил на сайт, что сделано. но всё равно тени нет :(

Comment: Добавьте еще блоку `card`  `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

У вас он и так находится за блоком `.card__content-right`, просто у него фон прозрачный, добавьте `background-color: #f5f6fa`

Comment: В вашем варианте еще надо будет тень добавить, так как на макете она есть. А блок `.card__content-right` ее не отбрасывает